# General solution for squared trigonometry questions: $\cos^2 x = 1$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

$\cos^2 x = 1$

How do you solve trig equations with a power?

Unsure what to do with the square?

I get this

- $\frac{1+\cos2x}2 =1$
- $\cos2x =1$
- $2x=2n\pi\pm0$
- $x=n\pi$

but the answer says $\pm n\pi$

Comment: $n\pi$ where $n\in\mathbb Z$ and $\pm n\pi$ where $n\in\mathbb N=\{0,1,2,...\}$ are just two different expressions for the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the identity
$$\cos^2(x)=\frac{1+\cos(2x)}{2}.$$
You should then be able to solve this for $x$ by way of the inverse.

Comment: is this identity something you are supposed to learn and apply?

Comment: Absolutely! In fact you may want to work out how to derive it. It is a very common identity (along with $\sin^2(x)$).

Comment: do you have a link to a site with these identities?

Comment: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities) is a good one. jump to the [Power Reduction Formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Power-reduction_formula) there.

Comment: please have a look at my edited working out, and tell me what i am doing wrong

Comment: Your conclusion is correct. You mis-wrote the identity. Note that $\pm n \pi$ is the same thing as $n \pi$ when $n$ is an element of the set of integers.

Comment: oh, yes i fixed it, so npi=+-npi?

Answer (score 2):

$\cos^2x-1=0$
$(\cos x -1)(\cos x +1)=0$

$\cos x =1 \ \ \  \  $ or  $\  \  \     \cos x = -1$

$x=0+2k \pi  \  \ $ or  $  \  \  \  x= \pi + 2 k \pi$

$ k =0, \pm 1, \pm 2, \ldots$

Answer (score 2):

$\cos^2 x = 1$

Just square root both sides to get:

$\cos x = \pm 1$

So any angles that have a cosine of $-1$ and any angles that have a cosine of $1$ will satisfy this equation.

$x = \{0+2\pi k, \pi+2 \pi k\},$ where $k$ is any integer.

So this solution set will generate all of the angles that have a cosine of either $-1$ or $1$ because when you add $2\pi$ to an angle you just get an angle that's in the same place which has the same cosine.

Comment: I also think this is by far the most straightforward way of looking at it.

Comment: Yeah, I don't know why everyone's using identities for such a simple equation.

Comment: I do like Kmitov's though.

Answer (score 1):

Using the identity: $cos^2x + sin^2x = 1$. So $sin^2x = 0$, and $sinx = 0$, so $x = n\pi$

Answer (score 0):

***Hint:***

$\cos^2(x) = \frac 1 2(\cos(2x) + 1)$

Comment: how did you get this?

Comment: @confused: $\cos^2 x - \sin^2 x = \cos2x$. Basic trig identity.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

$$\cos^2(x) = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2}\cos(2x)$$